# ConnectionToTheDatabaseFailed after Upgrade to dnn 9.3.2

Tags: dotnetnuke

DNN Upgrade error from 9.1 to 9.3.2 : After upgrade we observe that if we reboot server and immediately try to access the web site then we get error like 'Connection To The Database Failed'.This is happen only first time after server reboot. once we start receiving this error after then we continue receive this error irrespective of how many times we hit website. It is exists till we do IIS Restart or Application pool recyle manually.

Because of this issue we have paused server reboot schedule as well.

Please guide how to overcome from this.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but is it possible that SQL Server starts up slowly after the reboot.

Try waiting 5 minutes before going to the website.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually a bit surprised that you have this on a DNN 9 installation. I haven't seen it myself as of DNN 8.

I recall solving that by changing the startup type for IIS (in the services MMC) from "Automatic" to "Automatic (Delayed)". That should give SQL Server a decent chance to be started before IIS is.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to configure the IIS service being dependent on SQL Server (if both IIS and SQL Server are installed on the same machine):

```
sc config W3SVC depend=MSSQLSERVER
```

Take care, if you are using a named instance as in the SQL Server Express standard installation, the name could be MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS or whatever instead of MSSQLSERVER. Have a look at the properties of the service to find out.